# Why breadcrumb do not work properly on SharePoint page?

Tags: breadcrumb

I am working on a SharePoint 2013 site. By following the instruction [here](http://academy.bindtuning.com/lets-bring-the-breadcrumb-back-to-sharepoint-2013/) I can successfully add a "Navigation up breadcrumb icon" at top navigation. The site collection is created with Enterprise Wiki Template. The pages are stored under nested folder structure.

For example: http://sharepoint.com/sites/kb/pages/topic1/topic1-1/topic1-1-1/mytopic.aspx

When I navigate through each folder, the breadcrumb is shown correctly. For example,

```
|_Sharepoint Site
  |_Pages
    |_Topic 1
      |_Topic 1-1
        |_Topic 1-1-1
```

However when I reach mytopic.aspx, the breadcrumb is shown like this:

```
|_Sharepoint Site
|_My Topic
```

Why is that and can I workaround this? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Mark, 

Are you using 2 different master pages?

Comment: I created a test.master page based on seattle.master. After modifiy a few line about the breadcrumb, I apply test.master on both custom and system master page.